# macOS AppKit: Strange dragging behavior of modeless NSSavePanel

Tags: macos, appkit, nssavepanel

When I create a NSSavePanel to be modeless, the dragging behavior is very strange:

- It does not react to dragging attempts in the title bar
- When I initiate the drag in other areas of the panel, it will first jump down a few pixels and then dragging continues normally.

This is my code:

```
       NSSavePanel *sp = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
       // don't forget to set filename etc...
       [sp beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
           if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
                   //
               }
       }];
```

And also I have a problem, when some other apps become full screen, I want the save panel can over other apps, but not use

```
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

I use

```
[sp makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
[sp orderFrontRegardless];
```

but not work.

Thanks for the help, and merry christmas.

Comment: Don't really understand what is your question.

Answer (score 1):

The jump was a bug in AppKit, resolved in macOS 10.13.